# How to send a push message to a different device?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using parse.com services. I want to send a push message to a different client once the user clicks on a button.

So, in case no one understand me (and it happens a lot ;-)) my question is: How can I send a push message through Parse.com services to user A once user B clicks a button?

Comment: You can use the deviceType parameter when building a push

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parse push services so can you please give me an example?

Comment: Parse.com has thousands of tutorials. You should start there first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have relation between User and Installation table. I recommend to add User pointer to Installation table. That way users can use the App with multiple devices.

I recommend to add the push notification send functionality in Parse Cloud Code and call it from client app.

Example Cloud Code:

```
var userQueryPre = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQueryPre.equalTo("username", ToUserID);

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
userQuery.exists("user"); // filter out installations without users
userQuery.include("user"); // expand the user pointer
userQuery.matchesQuery("user", userQueryPre);

userQuery.find({
success: function(resultUsers) {
     Parse.Push.send({
         where: userQuery, // Set our Installation query
         data: { alert: "Message", badge: "Increment" }
     },{
         success: function () {response.success(""); },
         error: function (error) { response.error("") }
     });
```